# Lines and colorboxes in background of the text

Tags: colorbox

I am very new at latex and therefore  I am not really sure what I am searching for, so maybe I thought someone of you could help me!

I want - I am trying to modify some template for a cover letter, and add some transparent color boxes and lines in the -background- of the text.

What is it, what I am searching for? I now I can use

```
\rule
```

for drawing lines, but I want them to be in the background of the text, which I didn't manage to do with that command. Should I use colorbox, or something else?

And in general, should I create for this my own .class file..the internet is full of information, with templates having with dozens of details like \leftheades and so on..so maybe someone has also an advice for me where to start learning all of this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you're trying to achieve is not very clear. Could you explain in detail and/or post a hand-made sketch?

Comment: Hi Bernard, let my try one more time with words, if not I will create some example figure. So lets say I want to have a figure in the background of text, so you have a letter and some things written, and in the back you see a transparent cloud for example :)

Comment: In my opinion, there's no need to worry about creating your own class file at this point. Just use one of the standard classes, and focus on your content. Search for "cover letter" on this site and you should find some advice to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use `tikz` to draw in the background of a page.

Here comes a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [scale=10,text opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) {Some Text};
\draw[line width = 3pt, rounded corners=10mm] (1,-12) to (5,-12) to (5, -16);
\end{tikzpicture}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

The `blindtext` is to show that the drawing is actually in the background. You can find more information about `tikz` and drawing in the background in the [TikZ manual](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 249.

This is the output:

[image: Lines and text in the background]